# awk, sed or vim regex

Tags: regex, vim, sed, awk

I'm searching for the best way to add a string to an existing string while I don't want to replace the whole string.

```
self.fields_desc.append(BitField("foo", 0x3, 4))
```

sould be replaced by:

```
self.fields_desc.append(BitField("foo" + str(self.__class__.i), 0x3, 4))
```

Using which tool would allow me to do this with the less possible trouble? In vim I could do:

```
:%s/self.fields_desc.append(BitField("[a-zA-Z0-9]*", 0x[0-9]*, [0-9]*))/self.fields_desc.append(BitField("foo" + str(self.__class__.i), 0x3, 4))/g
```

But I don't know how I would tell vim to not replace the regex I wrote. Could you give me a hand on this please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use capturing groups (note the "\" before the "(" and ")", and the "\1", "\2" etc):

```
:%s/self\.fields_desc\.append(BitField(\("[a-zA-Z0-9]*"\), \(0x[0-9]\+\), \([0-9]\+\)))/self.fields_desc.append(BitField(\1 + str(self.__class__.i), \2, \3))/g
```

changes:

```java
self.fields_desc.append(BitField("foo", 0x3, 4))
self.fields_desc.append(BitField("test", 0x5, 3))
```

to

```java
self.fields_desc.append(BitField("foo" + str(self.__class__.i), 0x3, 4))
self.fields_desc.append(BitField("test" + str(self.__class__.i), 0x5, 3))
```

Note:

1. I've escaped the ".", as "." matches any character (except newline), and you want a literal "." character.
2. I've replaced `*` with `+` for the number matches: I doubt you want to match `self.fields_desc.append(BitField("foo", 0x,)` etc.
3. If you aren't sure whether the spacing is correct, i.e., you don't always have `self.fields_desc.append(BitField("foo", 0x3...` but sometimes `self.fields_desc.append(BitField("foo",0x3` or `self.fields_desc.append(BitField("foo",  0x3`, then add a `*` after the space characters. Although I'd suggest insteading standardising your code.

See [Regex grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and [The regex "dot"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html).

---

As sidyll says, it is probably better to learn to use the built-in character classes "\d", "\w" (see [Shorthand character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#shorthand)) and so on:

```
:%s/self\.fields_desc\.append(BitField(\("\w*"\), \(0x\d\+\), \(\d\+\)))/self.fields_desc.append(BitField(\1 + str(self.__class__.i), \2, \3))/g
```

This is both for brevity, and readability. Also, otherwise, readers will assume you have some special reason for defining your own character class (i.e., they will read it twice to make sure there's not some unknown character in there).

Comment: It's rare for me to give a downvote, but I can't resist: Why grouping? Why `[0-9]` instead of `\d`? Why not zero-width matches?

Comment: @sidyll: Because grouping is much easier to understand for someone who didn't know it before, and it more closely matches their original regex. Frankly, downvoting a working answer because you don't like the style is in pretty poor taste. You have a relevent point about escaping '.', the rest of that is just silly. (particularly for a one-shot vim regex)

Comment: It's not about style, it's all about wasting resources. Typing is one of them, memory for groups is another. I know it's a "one-shot" trow away, but things like character classes or zero-width matches are really important; so it's also not a matter of complicating with new things. If you learn these in simple cases like this one, even if you spend a little time more reading the help file, you win when it comes to developing a more complex expression.

Comment: I've now updated this to use the standard character classes. I haven't mentioned zero-width assertions as I think it will probably confuse more than anything, although I do reference your answer, so hopefully the interested will look there (and have +1ed it). You are definitely right, I shouldn't have given such a hacked response.

Answer (score 1):

Please please avoid unnecessary matches and replaces. Use built-in character classes. And escape those dots. There is no need to group things here.

```
:%s/self\.fields_desc\.append(BitField("\w*"\zs\ze, 0x\d, \d))/ + str(self.__class__.i)
```

You probably don't need the *g* flag, I doubt two of these will appear on the same line.

See `:h \zs` and `:h \ze`.

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about `\zs` and `\ze`. Wish I could favourite an answer :(

Comment: Are `\zs` and `\ze` POSIX or PCRE standard, or vim-specific? They make everything before (or after) zero-width assertions, like look-aheads/behinds, but without the restriction of constant-size?

Comment: @MGwynne: Well, Vim regex engine is as powerful as Perl's, sometimes even more, but with notation differences. I know Perl has a `\k` similar to `\zs`, but not sure if it has a flexible look around similar to `\ze`. And I don't think POSIX include these (not sure). Quite handy, eh? And easy to use. By the way, nice work on your answer, definitely one of those well written references that deserves 3 votes, but I can give just one.

Comment: @MGwynne: Maybe I didn't clarified it, but yes, that's what `\zs` and `\ze` do. It's like a mark to what will be used as match, `\z` **s** for start and **e** for end.

Comment: Indeed, very interesting! Makes me want to look into more advanced features of various regex engines more. Although I then get annoyed when various simple systems don't support them :(

Comment: It's clear from the vim documentation and your explanation :) I'm just thinking more about the underlying implementation. I guess `\zs` and `\ze` don't have the same restriction as look-aheads/behinds (that is, the look-ahead/behind needing to be constant-size), as the zero-width assertions for `\zs` and `\ze` always stretch to the beginning and end of the string (whereas look-aheads etc can appear anywhere)? Is there a reference somewhere with more information on the implementation details?

Comment: @MGwynne: Maybe the implementation of these happens to be very straightforward. It's possible that the match is performed normally, but then resets the position. I don't really know how a regex engine works in deep, but now I'm curious to have a look in regexp.c (Vim source).